# Javascript date returns a month ahead of the date specified when using numerical dates

Tags: javascript, date

This is driving me crazy!

```
console.log(new Date(2020, 11, 4));
```

A simple date, 4th of November 2020.

Output:

```
Fri Dec 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

WHAT!

So lets try an alternative:

```
const now = new Date()
console.log(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

Outputs:
Thu Oct 29 2020 10:12:56 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

Lets confirm some things now:

```
typeof now.getFullYear();
"number"

typeof now.getMonth();
"number"

typeof now.getDate();
"number"

typeof 2020
"number"

typeof 11
"number"

typeof 4
"number"
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Date constructor:

```
monthIndex
Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

So `new Date(2020, 0, 1)` is 01.01.2020, and your test case `new Date(2020, 11, 4)` is not Nov 4th, but Dec 4th.

Comment: Its a crazy JavaScript world...